# Genymotion Lollipop ADB issue

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I run `adb devices` and I get `adb server is out of date. killing` etc

deleted all adb instances then run adb devices and I got this:

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

so device is not showing!

Comment: have you tried to update your SDK?

Comment: @OneWay the difference  is that here killing all adb.exe and trying again shows no devices in the list of devices detected

Comment: @DrRiss14 are you using win8/8.1?

Comment: are you running without hyper-v? my installation (W8.1) do not works with hyper-v. Do [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/04/14/creating-a-no-hypervisor-boot-entry.aspx), reboot without hyper-v..  works for me.

Comment: @OneWay I am using win8.1 I have AMD FX-4100 CPU, does it have this? All I can find online is having HyperTranport...

Comment: @DrRiss14 [yes](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-FX-Series%20FX-4100.html), let me know if it works for you too, to answer your question.

Comment: @ONeWay thanks for your response so far.----------I went into "turn windows features on and off" and I found that I don't have hyper-v enabled-------------Also on the internet:"To support Hyper-V client, you must have a 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro or Windows 8 Enterprise with a 64-bit CPU that supports SLAT (Second Level Address Translation). You’ll also need at least 4GB of RAM. Hyper-V does support creation of both 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems in the VMs."----------I got 32-bit 8.1 pro installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your your virtual device connect automatically to the ADB tool by specifying a custom ADB tool,

1. Download Android Developer Tools (ADT) from the ADT Download page.
2. Extract the archive files in the folder of your choice.
3. Open Genymotion > Settings > ADB.
4. Check Use custom Android SDK tools.
5. Specify the path to the Android SDK by clicking Browse.
6. Click OK.
7. Reboot your virtual device.

You could also connect to the virtual device ip using this command

```
1. adb tcpip
2. adb connect (yourIp)
```